# An exterminator is coming to my apartment. Should I do anything with my bird?

Tags: safety, birds, poison, pest-control

An exterminator is coming to treat my apartment. I will not need to leave for the treatment (ie it is not being fumigated). Should I remove my bird from the premises while this is happening? If so, for how long?

---

As an update, I ended up not removing my bird from the apartment. One of the two rooms of my apartment was being treated, so I put her in the non-treated room prior to the exterminator arriving, and kept her there for about four hours after the treatment. She was next to an open window in this room.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(After calling an avian vet to double check)

Yes, the bird should be removed from the premises for at least 24 hours if possible. Upon returning, all surfaces that the bird regularly comes in contact with should be wiped down.

If it is not possible to remove the bird from the apartment, keep it as far away from the treatment area as possible in a well-ventilated room (ie air filters and windows open).

Comment: If it will be fumigated - air spray, the bird should be removed. If liquid will be sprayed on the floor or baits put out , follow the Vet advice.

Comment: The exterminator might be able to give you some heads-up on the issue - supposing he read the instructions of the substances he uses. He should already know which living beings will be negatively affected by coming in contact with the said substances.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I will be able to stay in the apartment for the treatment so it is not fumigation.

Comment: @virolino The exterminator of course insists it's safe, but I will follow the vet's advice as best as I can.

Comment: @jackwise: I was thinking more in the direction that the exterminator would tell you to take the bird away, and you should have listened. Now it is quite possible that the gas is mostly harmless, but if you can take the bird away, it will be definitely better. I up-voted this answer for a reason ;)